# Trying to play a sound when HTML button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am fairly new to web developement and I figured that using a button to play a sound would be an easy enough project. I tried first following a video online which used javascript within the html head that looked something like `<script> var myaudio= new Audio() and myaudio.src="go.wav" </script>` and on the button had `onmousedown="myaudio.play()"`as an attribute.

The second method I tried came from a question on here which wasn't using js but just HTML5. In my document I have `<audio id="myaudio" src="go.wav"> </audio>` and on the button I have `onmousedown='document.getElementId('myaudio').play()"` as an attirbute
Neither of these methods cause the sound to play. I have the sound file within the same folder as my project files. Like I said, I'm new to this particular stuff, and I haven't use Javascript at all. I figured this would require some js and would be a decent starting point. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my minimal code
It won't let me type my first attempt here due to a formatting issue I can't resolve, but the only difference is that there is `<script> var myaudio= new Audio() and myaudio.src="go.wav" </script>` in the head and on the button I had  `onmousedown="myaudio.play()"`as an attribute

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Ready Go Trainer </title>
            <audio id="myaudio" src="go.wav"> </audio>
        </head>

        <body>

            <button type="button" class="but" onmousedown="document.getElementById('myaudio').play()"> start </button>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `getElementId` isn't a function. Can you show your exact code as a [mcve] instead of pseudocode? Having to guess what your code might actually be doesn't make it easy to get you a relevant answer. Thanks.

Comment: Put the audio element in the body not the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the next two ways:

**Solution 1**:

```
function playSound() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.play();
}

<button onclick="playSound()">Play Sound</button>
<audio id="audio" src="./path/to/sound"></audio>
```

**Solution 2**:

```
function playSound(soundFile) {
  new Audio(soundFile).play();
}

<button onclick="playSound('./path/to/sound')">Play Sound</button>
```

Comment: I just tried implementing this, but still no wound plays. I tried with the audio element in both the head and the body. I also put the javascript within a script tag in the head just to make sure it wasn't a linking problem. I tried both methods. is there a problem with an audio file being too long? Or is there a format Issue I don't know about like maybe audio files have to be under a certain folder?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Are you sure that the path to the sound file is correct?

Comment: VS Code isn't telling me I have any errors, and my path should be correct. I have my go.wav file in the same folder as my page, my css, and my javascript. It is visible in the file view when in VS code. I wrote ```playsound(go.wav)``` as my path because I shouldn't have to move up or down a folder.

Comment: ok so uhh, apparently there was about 2 minutes of silence in the beginning of the audio file, and everytime I clicked the button it restarted it. I just hadn't had the project open long enough to hear it until tonight when it scared the crap out of me. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: Maybe next time would be a great idea to check the file yourself first, not through the website =)).

Comment: indeed haha @Daniel